# Can I use early access Google Font on my tumblr blog?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I want to use this early access Google Font:
https://fonts.google.com/earlyaccess#Noto+Nastaliq+Urdu+Draft

on my tumblr blog:
https://muneebkablog.tumblr.com

The theme installed is this one:
https://www.tumblr.com/theme/38737

It does support Google Fonts, but I do not know how to use an early access Google Font.

I have tried adding this after < head >
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notonastaliqurdudraft.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

but then I did not know how to edit the following html to use this font. Here's the code in the html.

```
html {
        font: 175%/1.5 {block:ifGoogleWebFont}{text:Google Web Font},{/block:ifGoogleWebFont} Avenir, Arial;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
```

Alternatively, I searched the web and came to know one can add custom CSS, so I tried to add the following code into 'Add Custom CSS':

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notonastaliqurdudraft.css);
body {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 10em;
}
*[lang=ur] {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu Draft', serif;
}
```

but again nothing seems to be working.

You might have noticed by now that I am not a coder at all. I am just a casual blogger trying to deal with html and CSS codes.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

To use any Google font, just use the code snippets that are provided on the web site. In your case, add these lines to your css file:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notonastaliqurdudraft.css);
```

You have done that already!

Source: https://fonts.google.com/earlyaccess#Noto+Nastaliq+Urdu+Draft

Your example code then applies this font only to elements that include the `lang` property, i.e. `<p lang="ur">`.

`*[lang=ur]` is called a (CSS) selector, the * is basically a wild card, that selects all elements - which has been modified to only match certain elements.

**My guess:**
There is no `lang` attribute in your html code - but I can't tell for now, because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I added:
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notonastaliqurdudraft.css);
to the 'Add custom CSS' box in tumblr editor.
Then I added 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu Draft' in the theme's 'Google Web Font' option.
And now it seems to be working; at least, in the theme editor.
When I click the 'update preview' button, it does show everything in that Nastaliq Font.
But as soon as I exit the editor, it again shows everything in the previous font; I think, it is Arial.
Should I add *[lang=ur] somewhere in the html?
Should I share the entire theme's html?
Will that help?

Comment: Maybe you could change your entry post to contain valid links (there are no links to your blog i.e.), so that we can inspect your source code. But, if there is no single element that contains the lang property, it won't work anyways.

Comment: Thank you! I have added links in the post. Could you please have a look.

Comment: You had it correct when I was on your site about an hour ago. 
Maybe you just had to refresh your page completely (CTRL + F5 on Firefox)

Comment: Is it showing the Nastaliq font in your browser? I just installed Firefox after reading your comment, but it does not seem to show my desired font.

Comment: I'm not familiar with arabic fonts, but here is a screenshot how it looks on my browser: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/4kkB 
Make sure to put the import statement on top of your custom css and use:
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu Draft', serif;
} i.e.

Answer (score 0):

@Muneeb Ahmed, @elasticman is correct

Here is the working code with Google Fonts Early Access https://fonts.google.com/earlyaccess

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notonastaliqurdu.css);
         body {    
         font-family: 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu', serif;
         font-size: 36px;
         color: blue;
         text-align: right;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>السلام علیکم<br>خوش آمدید  </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]